# WordPress toggle menu closes too fast on smartphone

Tags: android, jquery, ios, wordpress

I have a WordPress theme that switches to the toggle menu in mobile.  However, when you try to use it on a phone it disappears before you can click on a link. The menu is long enough that it doesn't show unless you scroll down.  Touching the screen to scroll down results in the menu closing.

If I size the browser down to mobile and use my computer's touchscreen, the menu opens and works perfectly, allowing me to scroll then choose my link.  But on both an Android phone and an iPhone, it closes too quickly.

I tried using a menu plugin to bypass the theme menu, but ended up with two toggle menus in the header.

So.  Can I either fix the theme's menu button (ideal solution) or find a way to bypass it without killing the rest of the navigation and use a plugin?

The site is http:/www.pmi-global.net.

Thank you.

Comment: Works ok for me on Firefox for Android as long as I don't try to scroll the menu stays open

Comment: Right.  But I need people to be able to scroll and see the menu so they can navigate the site.  How do I do that?

Comment: Somehow I missed that in your question. Can you paste the menu script? Personally I'd think this behavior is preferred as I can see the whole menu without scrolling. I'd look into creating a smaller menu or break it into multiple drawers.

Comment: I have 3 versions of the menu.  Multiple drawers didn't solve the problem of it disappearing if you want/need to scroll.  My client is VERY particular, so changing the menu too much is pretty much impossible.  Trust me.  What script do you mean?  I know where the function.php stuff is and will post that.  If you mean something else, let me know and I'll dig it up.

Comment: Okay I have navigation.js, and nav-menu.php.  Which one would be helpful?